# Java String URL Validation

Tags: java, regex, validation

I am trying to validate s String url in my java application using @Pattern annotation of the javax validation library.

```
@Pattern(message = "Must be a valid URL", regexp = "https?:\\/\\/(www\\.)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\\+~#=]{1,256}\\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\\+.~#?&//=]*)")
```

When i submit a url in the url in this format; `https://www.test.com` it is successful but url in this format `https://api-apps.testapp.systems/test-service/v1/test`, it fails the validation.

The issue is with the `.com` The same url with `.systems` fail but with `.com` passes.

How can i make my regular expression allow all kinds of urls .com, .edu or .systems regardless ??

Comment: I see that your regex contains a lot of digits matching and I don't know if it's all necessary in your case, can you try this one and see if it matches you need: `^http(s?)://(w{3}\.)?[\w\.\-\/]*$`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `@URL` Annotation or `org.apache.commons.validator.UrlValidator` to do that.

Example:

```java
        UrlValidator crunchifyURLValidator = new UrlValidator();
        
        String url = "https://crunchify.com";
        if (crunchifyURLValidator.isValid(url)) {
            crunchifyLog("Hey. URL " + url + " is valid");
        } else {
            crunchifyLog("Hey. URL " + url + " is not valid");
        }
```

Comment: In my opinion, the focus of the answer should be on the regular expression, not in providing a different solution specifically for URLs. What if the OP has a similar problem in the future with a regular expression that is _not_ an URL?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the lenght of string permitted by the regexp for the TLD, which was {1,6}--
`.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\\b` i expanded the range and it accommodated a longer TLD name.

Comment: Can you expand on your solution? "_i_ [sic] _expanded your solution..._" is too vague to be a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\\b
```

this regex says that any lowercase uppercase or number but the string length shouldn't be inferior of 1 or supperior of 6 caracter

you have just to increase the length to max you expected  for example "systems" has 7 caracters you do:

```
.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,7}\\b
```

or

```
.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,8}\\b
```

to be sure